# Nutritional Label dont reach 100% total when adding all component?

Tags: nutrition

When i read a lean Ham nutrion fact label (In france) i see (roughly):

For a 100grams: 
Protein 21g
Glucide 0.4g
Lipides 1g

This doesn t add up to 100grams.. So what is the rest ? (Almost all label i see out there never reach 100%)

Comment: Different countries have different requirements for nutritional labels.  Are French nutritional labels always required to report on protein, fat, and carbohydrates?  Even then, are they allowed to exclude certain classes? And don't forget about water weight with things like ham.

Comment: Additionally, at least in the US, if the nutrient in question doesn't make up a certain percentage of the item, they are not required to list it.

Comment: The scope we have outlined in our [faq] states that nutrition topics that aren't related to physical fitness or exercise are off-topic. The current state of your question doesn't fit, but it can be reopened if it were edited to be. Unfortunately, there isn't another SE site that takes this particular type of topic.

Comment: @Matt Chan Might want to change the Page description then cause it reads Fitness and Nutrition from google: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&newwindow=1&sa=X&ei=PE4QULz2Au-R0QWh7YDQAg&ved=0CEkQvwUoAA&q=stackexchange+nutrition&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=f2e8df08ae46d1ed&biw=1920&bih=1079.. Plus that s a but narrow minded as anyone who trains will confirm that most part of fitness training goes through nutrition nutrition..

Comment: Are you going through a training program? What goals are you looking to achieve?

Comment: @Matt Chan I am currently just getting back in shape after few years of laziness.. But really my point is that i find it very strange to exclude nutrition from a fitness forum especially since as you said there is no SE that covers this part either..

Comment: @Berin Loritsch Duh i totally forgot about water.. Thanks i guess that is probably the case in most aliments.

Comment: Voted to re-open, a lot of answers on fitness.SE recommend measuring nutritional intake in an OCD fashion, being able to interpret nutritional labels is a pre-requisite for that

Comment: @RobinAshe A lot of questions on fitness.SE require basic math skills, but that doesn't make this a place for math questions.